# Can I stop STDOUT printing object information?

Tags: powershell, stdout

I'm running Powershell using the `WScript.Shell` COM object:

```
def Powershell.exec(data)
    #Encoding ensures there'll be no issues with complex quoted data
    require 'base64'
    data = Base64.strict_encode64(data.encode("utf-16le"))

    #Execute encoded commands:
    require 'win32ole'
    shell = WIN32OLE.new("WScript.Shell")
    app = shell.exec("powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -EncodedCommand \"" + data + "\"")
    return {:STDOUT=>app.StdOut.ReadAll(),:STDERR=>app.StdErr.ReadAll()}
end
```

I'm running the following powershell script:

```
$data = ConvertFrom-Json $data

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#region begin GUI{ 

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize = '500,400'
$Form.text = "Form"
$Form.TopMost = $false
$form.Resize = $false
$form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedToolWindow'

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.text = "OK"
$okButton.width = 150
$okButton.height = 50
$okButton.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(96,330)
$okButton.Add_Click({
    ForEach($item in $ListView1.SelectedIndices){
        Write-Host $item
    }
    $Form.close()
})

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.text = "Cancel"
$cancelButton.width = 150
$cancelButton.height = 50
$cancelButton.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(256,330)
$cancelButton.add_click({
    $Form.close()
})

$ListView1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$ListView1.text = "listView"
$ListView1.width = 490
$ListView1.height = 300
$ListView1.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(5,5)
$ListView1.MultiSelect = 1
$ListView1.View = 'Details'
$ListView1.FullRowSelect = 1
$ListView1.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,20'

#Generate headers
ForEach($d in $data.head){
    $col = $ListView1.columns.add($d)
    $col.width = -2
}

#Generate items
ForEach($item in $data.body){
    $lvi = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($item)
    For($i=1;$i -lt $item.length; $i++){
        $lvi.SubItems.Add($item[$i])
    }
    $ListView1.items.add($lvi)
}

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($okButton, $cancelButton ,$ListView1))

[Console]::Out.Flush() 
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

However currently the big problem is that when reading the STDOUT from `WScript.Shell` I get this:

```
Name      : 
BackColor               : Color [Window]
Bounds                  : {X=0,Y=1015,Width=486,Height=35}
Checked                 : False
Focused                 : False
Font                    : [Font: Name=Microsoft Sans Serif, Size=20, Units=3, 
                          GdiCharSet=1, GdiVerticalFont=False]
ForeColor               : Color [WindowText]
Group                   : 
ImageIndex              : -1
ImageKey                : SK46587402
ImageList               : 
IndentCount             : 0
Index                   : 28
ListView                : System.Windows.Forms.ListView, Items.Count: 29, 
                          Items[0]: ListViewItem: {hw_node}
Name                    : 
Position                : {X=4,Y=1015}
Selected                : False
StateImageIndex         : -1
SubItems                : {ListViewSubItem: {hw_subcatchment}, 
                          ListViewSubItem: {SK46587402}}
Tag                     : 
Text                    : hw_subcatchment
ToolTipText             : 
UseItemStyleForSubItems : True

BackColor : Color [Window]
Bounds    : {X=0,Y=0,Width=0,Height=0}
Font      : [Font: Name=Microsoft Sans Serif, Size=8.25, Units=3, 
            GdiCharSet=0, GdiVerticalFont=False]
ForeColor : Color [WindowText]
Tag       : 
Text      : SK46587502
Name      : 

BackColor               : Color [Window]
Bounds                  : {X=0,Y=1050,Width=486,Height=35}
Checked                 : False
Focused                 : False
Font                    : [Font: Name=Microsoft Sans Serif, Size=20, Units=3, 
                          GdiCharSet=1, GdiVerticalFont=False]
ForeColor               : Color [WindowText]
Group                   : 
ImageIndex              : -1
ImageKey                : SK46587502
ImageList               : 
IndentCount             : 0
Index                   : 29
ListView                : System.Windows.Forms.ListView, Items.Count: 30, 
                          Items[0]: ListViewItem: {hw_node}
Name                    : 
Position                : {X=4,Y=1050}
Selected                : False
StateImageIndex         : -1
SubItems                : {ListViewSubItem: {hw_subcatchment}, 
                          ListViewSubItem: {SK46587502}}
Tag                     : 
Text                    : hw_subcatchment
ToolTipText             : 
UseItemStyleForSubItems : True
```

For about 2100 lines until finally I get the output I wrote to stdout with `Write-Host`... Is there any way that I can 'silence' Powershell spewing out the objects that it has created?

Answer (score 1):

As a shot in the dark I tried adding `[void]` to several method calls in `Generate items`:

```
#Generate items
ForEach($item in $data.body){
    $lvi = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($item)
    For($i=1;$i -lt $item.length; $i++){
        [void]$lvi.SubItems.Add($item[$i])
    }
   [void]$ListView1.items.add($lvi)
}
```

To my surprise, this prevents the issue I was having. I guess the object was being created and returned by the `add()` method, so I had to tell Powershell specifically that I didn't require the data? Seems a little odd that this is required, but glad I managed to get it working.

Comment: You can also pipe to Out-Null

Comment: How about reading [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a7fwahe(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Clijsters Reading the docs only helps if you already know that Powershell will output all objects which are returned by any called function... I had never known the use of `[void]` before using it here...

Comment: Why should PowerShell do any other than returning what has to be returned. Why do you think this is undocumented behavior? What is special for voids? Sorry for blaming; just saying

Comment: @Clijsters In any normal programming language, to output ANY data to stdout, one has to declare it. If one is used to normal programming languages, one might assume that Powershell is the same and that whenever you want to write to STDOUT you do so via Write-Host. However this behavior shows that Powershell will write to STDOUT in certain scenarios. This is my point. This turns out to be standard powershell behavior, but I did not know that, hence why this question exists.

Comment: PowerShell isn't a _normal_ programming language, it's also a repl. One can read this in the introduction section of every getting started book. Even in JShell, which is Java, some might consider a normal programming language, this is default behaviour...

Comment: @Clijsters "PowerShell isn't a normal programming language" < If I had known the behaviour of Powershell from the onset, do you think I would be asking this question?... I clearly didn't know the standard behaviour, so I have no idea what your problem is... I'm not omniscient...